# gcc standard headers maze

Tags: gcc, include, stdio

I'm trying to build gcc for cross compilation (host - Mac OS X, target - ARM), this is the link to my previous question and answer([How to make ARM cross compilation on Mac OS X (error: invalid listing option `r' - cross compiling error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197735/fatal-error-invalid-listing-option-r-cross-compiling-error))

I need to build libgcc, so I run the command `make all-target-libgcc`, everything seems fine until I encounter this error:

```
/Users/smcho/Desktop/gcc/gcc-build-arm/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/smcho/Desktop/gcc/gcc-build-
arm/./gcc/ -B/opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/bin/ -B/opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/lib/ -isystem 
/opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/include -isystem /opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/sys-include    -g -O2 -mthumb -
O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-
qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -fno-
inline -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector   -fno-inline -I. -I. - 
I../../.././gcc -I../../../../gcc-4.8.3/libgcc -I../../../../gcc-4.8.3/libgcc/. -
I../../../../gcc-4.8.3/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../../gcc-4.8.3/libgcc/../include  -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -
o _eprintf.o -MT _eprintf.o -MD -MP -MF _eprintf.dep -DL_eprintf -c ../../../../gcc-
4.8.3/libgcc/libgcc2.c -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
../../../../gcc-4.8.3/libgcc/libgcc2.c:2043:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
                   ^
```

In short, libgcc2.c can't find the `stdio.h` header file. 
I use gcc-4.8 from `brew`, so I already have a include directory in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/4.9.1/include`, and I thought this is a simple fix. The issue is that `<stdio.h>` is buried in `c++/tr1`. Furthermore, it's just one line `#include <tr1/cstdio>` that points to the other header in a sub directory.

From the command line, I know that I have two directories (`-isystem /opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/sys-include` and `/opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/include`) that I can symbolically link to; the two directories does not exist.

However, I'm lost as I'm not sure what paths to symbolically link them to. I simply tried to link `/opt/cross/arm-elf-eabi/include` to `.../4.9.1/include/c++/tr1` in order make `stdio.h` to be found, but as it uses , I have another compilation error.

I tried many combinations, but I always end up with errors. This is just simple C code, so I don't think I need complex C++ headers.

- Is there simple way to solve this problem? I mean, can I just download the C header files and link the directory to `include` directory?
- How gcc (not g++) find the `stdio.h` in this include directory maze? How is the setup?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mac os x, the header files are located in `/usr/include`. I could make the symbolic link to point to this directory to solve this issue.