# Qemu flash boot up does not work

Tags: flash, arm, qemu

I have a rather old (published in 2009) embedded ARM linux book that uses `u-boot` and `qemu`.
The usage of `qemu` with the `u-boot` binary explained in the book is as follows:

```
qemu-system-arm -M connex -pflash u-boot.bin -nographic
```

It uses qemu 0.9.1, and mine is 2.1.0:

```
qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

When I executed the same command, however, I got these error messages.

```
qemu-system-arm: failed to read the initial flash content
qemu-system-arm: Initialization of device cfi.pflash01 failed
```

What might be wrong? Is this from the new command parameter? I have [this site](http://emreboy.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/how-to-cross-compile-u-boot-and-work-it-on-qemu/) that uses different command, but when I tried that I see a blank screen.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel u-boot.bin
```

I use Mac OS X maverick for qemu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=4096
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -o add.o add.S
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -Ttext=0x0 -o add.elf add.o
arm-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy -O binary add.elf add.bin
dd if=add.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc
qemu-system-arm -M connex -pflash flash.bin -nographic -serial /dev/null -gdb tcp::1234 -S
```

where add.S is:

```
.text
entry: b start
arr:    .byte 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
eoa:
.align
start:  
    ldr r0, =eoa
    ldr r1, =arr
    mov r3, #0
loop:
    ldrb r2, [r1], #1
    add r3, r2, r3
    cmp r1, r0
    bne loop
stop:   b stop
```

And it seems that program works fine ...

```
qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.5), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Comment: I add that http://winfred-lu.blogspot.com/2011/12/arm-u-boot-on-qemu.html gives another explanation on how to use the debugger.

Comment: I also summarized the process to build and test ARM cross compilation on Mac OS X - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197735/how-to-make-arm-cross-compilation-on-mac-os-x-error-invalid-listing-option-r

Comment: I tried the same code but failed. My qemu is 2.3, and compiler is "arm-linux-gnueabi-" installed from apt-get.The error message is "qemu-system-arm: Initialization of device cfi.pflash01 failed: failed to read the initial flash content"

Answer (score 2):

With Alex's help, I could run gumstix on qemu.

1. The binary should be transformed into flash format with dd command.

   - `dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=4096`
   - `dd if=u-boot.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc`
2. The qemu should be given a parameter to use stdio for serial communication

   `qemu-system-arm -M connex -pflash flash.bin -serial stdio`

Then, I see the screen output:

```
pxa2xx_clkcfg_write: CPU frequency change attempt


U-Boot 1.1.4 (Oct  6 2014 - 14:51:37) - 200 MHz - 

*** Welcome to Gumstix ***

U-Boot code: A3F00000 -> A3F23138  BSS: -> A3F58258
RAM Configuration:
Bank #0: a0000000 64 MB
Flash: 16 MB
Using default environment

SMC91C1111-0
Net:   SMC91C1111-0
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Instruction Cache is ON
### JFFS2 loading 'boot/uImage' to 0xa2000000
Scanning JFFS2 FS:  done.
find_inode failed for name=boot
load: Failed to find inode
### JFFS2 LOAD ERROR<0> for boot/uImage!
GUM>
```

Refer to the source code([gumstix.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/qemu.git/tree/hw/gumstix.c)).