# Booting u-boot in Mac OS X's qemu

Tags: gcc, arm, qemu, u-boot

I'm trying to build u-boot, and run it in qemu on Mac OS X. 
I found this site, and followed the instructions:
http://imvoid.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/booting-uboot-in-qemu/

For cross compilation on Mac OS X, I could build the tools - [How to make ARM cross compilation on Mac OS X (error: invalid listing option `r' - cross compiling error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197735/how-to-make-arm-cross-compilation-on-mac-os-x-error-invalid-listing-option-r)

For u-boot, I tried the newest edition (2014) that causes core dump, and some earlier version (2010) that doesn't compile, so I used the 2013/10 version (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1234/2014/u-boot-2013.10.tar.bz2) to get the uboot.bin.

However, when I run the binary with `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel u-boot.bin;`, there is no crash, but I see nothing from the screen.

What might be wrong? I uploaded the binary.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1234/2014/u-boot.bin

And the 2014 version that crashes.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1234/2014/u-boot_2014.bin

Comment: Does it work without -nographic?

Comment: It does not work with or without -nographic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ELF format file `u-boot`, instead of `u-boot.bin`.

```
$ qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel u-boot


U-Boot 2014.10-rc2-00312-g9169305 (Oct 06 2014 - 20:43:26)

DRAM:  128 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
Flash: Flash protect error at address 37ec0000
Flash protect error at address 37fc0000
64 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   SMC91111-0
Warning: SMC91111-0 using MAC address from net device

Warning: Your board does not use generic board. Please read
doc/README.generic-board and take action. Boards not
upgraded by the late 2014 may break or be removed.
VersatilePB #
```

I built `u-boot` commit `91693055995733e268874ae75568ae316233e116` on my `OS X 10.9.5` system.  I used the ARM toolchain binaries available [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download). Untar `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805-mac.tar.bz2` anywhere (e.g. `$HOME`)

```
$ git clone http://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
$ cd u-boot
$ make versatilepb_config
$ make CROSS_COMPILE=~/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-
```

I used `Qemu` from `Homebrew`.

```
$ qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Comment: Could you care to explain why the ELF version works while the binary doesn't? The other post (http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) has an example that the binary approach just works with -kernel parameter.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm afraid.  The blog post you reference is from 2010.  Qemu and u-boot development moves really fast.  You might find some information if you search through the Qemu and/or u-boot mailing lists.

Comment: Looks like qemu has special code to load u-boot images http://tinyurl.com/mq6w8p3 . It could be a bug in Qemu or u-boot. Maybe loading binary images is no longer supported. Please write back here if you decide to dig into this and find something :)

Comment: http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html has "‘-kernel bzImage’
Use bzImage as kernel image. The kernel can be either a Linux kernel or in multiboot format."; I wonder ELF format may have something to do with this multi boot format.

Comment: I believe bzImage and multiboot are two kinds of x86-specific image formats.  The documentation that accompanies -kernel is not up-to-date and likely inaccurate for several architectures.  As an example, the arm_load_kernel() code that I pointed out earlier does not match this documentation.